# How to call "flash.ocx" with python by filename

Tags: python, flash, pyqt, activex, ocx

I want to create a player using "flash.ocx".
It looks like this.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QAxContainer, QtWidgets
import pickle

class Ui_Flash(QAxContainer.QAxWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Flash, self).__init__()
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setControl("{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}")
        self.dynamicCall("LoadMovie(long,string)", 0, r"test.swf")
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Flash()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, this method is implemented using the COM interface. It can use either "ProgID" or "CLSID".
But I want to find an implementation method that can be called directly by the file name.
It looks like ...

```py
self.setControl("D:\\Flash.ocx")  # The "self.setControl" func is an example, which does not mean that the example is correct.
```

You can use pyqt or other UI designs, such as Tkinter.
So, how do I do it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#control-prop), `setControl()` also supports file paths. Try using the standard path syntax (with slashes, not backslashes) and ensure that the path is correct.

Comment: However, if I use it this way, it will block. `self.setControl("D:\\Flash.ocx")`. Can you write an executable demo code, please. Thanks.

Comment: My system is windows, so I use backslash. In my current environment, both slashes and backslashes working.

Comment: Sorry, I can't, as I don't use Windows. I know that windows uses backslashes, but that's not the point (especially considering that Qt internally always uses slashes): just **try** it. It shouldn't be that, but at least you can be *sure* about that. Also, are you sure that that control can just work with *only* that file? You should do a dependency test when using the clsid version and see if that library uses other resources.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will depend on other resources. Is there any good method or tool to do dependency testing?